Unitaries are block diagonal for unitary equivalence of two block diagonal operators
I am trying to prove the following statement.

Let $\begin{bmatrix} A &0\\ 0& S \end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} B &0\\ 0& S \end{bmatrix}$ two block diagonal opeartors which are unitarily equivalent, then $A$ and $B$ are unitarily equivalent.

I tried to prove statement with $S=I$. I want to show if $\begin{bmatrix} A &0\\ 0& I \end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} B &0\\ 0& I \end{bmatrix}$ are unitarily equivalent then $A$ and $B$ are unitarily equivalent. Let $U=\begin{bmatrix} U_{11} & U_{12}\\ U_{21} & U_{22} \end{bmatrix}$ be the unitary for the unitary equivalence.
Using $\begin{bmatrix} A &0\\ 0& I \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} U_{11} & U_{12}\\ U_{21} & U_{22} \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} U_{11} & U_{12}\\ U_{21} & U_{22} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} B &0\\ 0& I \end{bmatrix}$ we get
$U_{21}=U_{21}B$ and
$AU_{12}=U_{12}$
If we could assume $\|A\| <1$ and $\|B\| <1$, $1-A$ and $1-B$ would be invertible and we could show that both $U_{12}$ and $U_{21}$ are zero which would prove our claim for this special case. But I could not assume that the norm is less than $1$.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Maybe the problem is the word “operator”. If you restrict the question to matrices you may be able to get a proof by relying on ”finite dimensional only” objects, like the determinant.

@LeeFisher Is the result true for matrices though? I can see that $A$ and $B$ have to be similar, via a Jordan canonical form argument, but I cannot figure out how to show they are unitarily equivalent.

I kind of doubt that it is true for matrices. I wasn’t able to prove either way.

@Gao For the matrix case it follows from the Specht's theorem. It says "Two matrices A and B are unitarily equivalent if and only if tr W(A, A*) = tr W(B, B*) for all words W". But I wanted to have some proof with some matrix calculations. Can you share how you have shown that $A$ and $B$ are similar for the matrices?

@Arindam Ah, you’re right. This does follow from Specht’s theorem. As for similarity, $A \oplus S$ and $B \oplus S$ being unitarily equivalent (being similar is enough) implies they have the same Jordan canonical form, so same eigenvalues and same spatial and algebraic multiplicities of each eigenvalue. Since the eigenvalues of $A \oplus S$ are the union of those of $A$ and those of $S$, and spatial and algebraic multiplicities of the eigenvalues are the sums of the multiplicities in $A$ and $S$, and the same holds for $B$, you can just subtract the multiplicities in $S$ from…

@Arindam … the multiplicities in $A \oplus S$ and $B \oplus S$ to obtain that $A$ and $B$ have the same eigenvalues, with the same spatial and algebraic multiplicities, so their Jordan canonical forms coincide, whence they are similar.

The statement is not true. Let $T$ be the unilateral shift, $A = T$, $B = T \otimes I_{l^2}$, and $S = T \otimes I_{l^2}$, then $A \oplus S$ and $B \oplus S$ are unitarily equivalent but $A$ and $B$ are not.

The statement’s not even true when $S = I_{l^2}$. For example, again let $T$ be the unilateral shift. Then $A = T$ and $B = T \oplus I_{l^2}$ are not unitarily equivalent, but $A \oplus S = T \oplus I_{l^2}$ and $B \oplus S = T \oplus I_{l^2} \oplus I_{l^2}$ are.

You don’t even need unilateral shifts. $A = -I_{l^2}$, $B = -I_{l^2} \oplus I_{l^2}$, and $S = I_{l^2}$ work just as well. By changing $-I_{l^2}$ to $\frac{1}{2}I_{l^2}$, you can even make one of $A$ and $B$ have norm strictly less than $1$. (You can even make $A$ be $0$ by changing $-I_{l^2}$ to $0$ on $l^2$.)
